# How to set gopath per application in upstart?

Tags: ubuntu, go, upstart

If I have 2 apps developed in go, and I want them to each have a copy their dependencies (and not have all dependencies in a central location), and each will be run by upstart in ubuntu, how do I indicate a different GOPATH for each application?

Comment: I'm not sure why GOPATH comes into play at all. Shouldn't upstart start already compiled binaries of your application, at which point GOPATH becomes irrelevant

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Dominik. Still very newbie to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can write shellscripts to start your go application and set the needed environment there. The upstart job then calls the shellscript instead of the application themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As Dominik Said in the Comments. You don't need to set the `GOPATH` once the go binary is compiled. GOPATH works only in the build phase.